# How to test the type of an error in Box<dyn Error>?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, typeerror

I have a function that returns `Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>`. I am writing a test case for this function where the function should return an error of variant `VerifyError::LinearCombinationError` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=29ad4c8566691f4f60bd834df8894394)):

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display, Formatter};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum VerifyError {
    LinearCombination,
}

impl Error for VerifyError {}

impl Display for VerifyError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self)
    }
}

fn return_result() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    Err(Box::new(VerifyError::LinearCombination))
}

pub fn main() {
    let res = return_result();
    println!("debug print is: {:?}", res);

    // Program does not compile when below line is not commented out
    // assert_eq!(Some(VerifyError::LinearCombination), res.err());
}
```

Uncommenting the line gives the error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:26:5
   |
26 |     assert_eq!(Some(VerifyError::LinearCombination), res.err());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `VerifyError`, found struct `Box`
   |
   = note: expected enum `Option<VerifyError>`
              found enum `Option<Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`
   = note: this error originates in a macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I am using Rust 1.53.0.

Comment: *an error of type `VerifyError::LinearCombinationError`* — enum variants are not types of their own. The _type_ is just `VerifyError`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Error::is`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.is) to test if the error trait object has a specific concrete type or [`Error::downcast`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.downcast) to convert it to that concrete type:

```rust
use std::error::Error;

fn example() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    Err(std::io::Error::last_os_error().into())
}

#[test]
fn is_from_io_error() {
    let e = example().err().unwrap();
    assert!(e.is::<std::io::Error>());

    let _e = e.downcast::<std::io::Error>().unwrap();
}
```

---

If you care about the specific error, I'd encourage you to avoid using trait objects. The point of trait objects is that you don't *need* to know what the concrete type is.

Instead, you could use a library that helps you construct error types, such as my [SNAFU](https://crates.io/crates/snafu). This usage shows wrapping errors in an enum that can be pattern matched to test the specific type:

```rust
use snafu::{Snafu, ResultExt}; // snafu = "0.7.0-beta.0"

#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
enum Error {
    Example { source: std::io::Error }
}

fn example() -> Result<(), Error> {
    Err(std::io::Error::last_os_error()).context(ExampleSnafu)
}

#[test]
fn is_from_io_error() {
    let e = example();
    assert!(matches!(e, Err(Error::Example { .. })))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works to test the type of the error that is thrown. Adapted from your answer: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4878763213238f62ca8329c8d82fc868

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `is_ok` and `is_err` functions of the `Result` type to test the type of variant if you don't care about the specific error itself.

An example would be:

```rs
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn should_return_error() {
        assert!(super::return_result().is_err());
    }
}
```

Note: It's assumed the `return_result` function is defined in the parent module. Therefore, it can be accessed with `super`.